# How to perform parallel execution of tests in nightwatchjs from grunt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, protractor, nightwatch.js

I am trying to execute the tests in parallel from grunt file in nightwatchjs. I tried by placing the following code in batch file and called the batch file from grunt,  `node nightwatch -e chrome,Firefox`, it is working fine but it does not give me the perfect solution as i need to change the paths everytime when executing with nightwatch and with grunt. (**while importing data, gurnt takes ‘./’ whereas nightwatch takes ‘../’ from different file**) so can someone help me in executing the tests in parallel from grunt. Thanks in advance.